# Не могу передать байтовый массив в контроллер

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

У меня изображения храняться в бд в формате байтового массива, через форич отлично все выводит, но когда я хочу открыть страницу для работы с определенным изображением, выдает ошибку про то, что я передаю не байтовое значение, хотя когда шагаю по коду и смотрю передаваемое значение, там отображает byte[значения].

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw("<img style='width:80px; height:60px;' src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
                + Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image) + "\" />")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Personal", new { id = item.Id, item.Image }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Delete", "Personal", new { id = item.Id}, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

в Edit я передаю айди изображения и его байтовый массив
Сам Edit:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, byte[] image)
{
    ApplicationUser au = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    Picture pic = new Picture { Id = id, Image = image};
    return View(pic);
}
```

Структура таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pictures] (
[Id]                 INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Size]               NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
[Image]              VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
[UserId]             NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
[ApplicationUser_Id] NVARCHAR (128)  NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Pictures] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Pictures_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUser_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationUser_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
);
```

[image: Ошибка]

Мне кажется, что можно передать элемент коллекции как-то проще, но немогу заселектить в контроллере один элемент по айди.

Comment: попробовал через Linq запрос вытащить, но всеровно ругаеться на тип

`public ActionResult Edit(int id, byte[] image)
        {
            ApplicationUser au = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            Picture pic = new Picture();
            foreach (var item in au.Pictures)
            {
                pic = from p in au.Pictures where p.Id == id select p;
            }
            //Picture pic = new Picture { Id = id, Image = image};
            return View(pic);
        }`

Comment: нужно передавать не просто массив байт, а в кодировке BASE64, о чем и написано в ошибке. В первом фрагменте у вас есть преобразование в BASE64, а в Edit я его не наблюдаю.

Comment: @rdorn постойте, но в BASE64 я перевожу перед выводом изображения, а в Edit мне нужно передать байтовый массив изображения, чтоб на другой странице вывести изображение конвертировав в Base64 переданый массив. Вообще это все немного через задницу, но я незнаю как вытянуть элемент с коллекции Pictures, поэтому приходиться проводить такие манипуляции с передачей масива.

Comment: ну вы же по http передаете клиенту данные? http - текстовый формат, BASE64 - совместимый с http, бинарный формат, все байты которого имеют печатное представление, в виде.допустимых отображаемых символов.

Comment: @rdorn оно то так, но выдает ошибку на слишком длинный урл

Comment: а вот это уже другой вопрос, и я, к сожалению с ним не помогу, в web-программировании довольно поверхностно разбираюсь

Comment: не получилось воссоздать проблему в тесте, а можно увидеть представление Edit? В нем же ошибка происходит?

Comment: @Ruslan_K 
`@model Dip_prj1.Models.Picture
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
             @Html.Raw("<img style='width:80px; height:60px;' src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
                                + Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image) + "\" />")>
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Вернуться к списку", "UserDetails", "Personal", new { id = User.Identity.GetUserId() }, null)
    </div>`

Comment: посмотрите в отладке Model.Image не содержит в начале строки заголовок `data:image/png;base64` как в [этом ответе](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30525829/3373603), если да то его нужно удалить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем передать через url изображению?? передайте просто id изображения и получите из базы по ид.
лучше бы создать какой нид Action типа DownloadPicture(imageId) и который будет возвращать изображению или base64 и можно было потом использовать

```
<img src="DownloadPicture(imageId)"/>
```